# Ruby script extracts wrong value when executed with crontab

Tags: linux, ruby, cron

OS: Amazon Linux

I have a Ruby script that connects to a site, then it searches with an XPath request for a **div** block where is the stats counter I want to parse.

Then it compares the number from the site with the current value in the database, if the number has increased it sends me an email.

The problem is that, then I run the script from the current directory it works.

1. The script parses the block of text which contains a value.
2. I extract the value with Regex like this (/\d/)
   ...

But when it the script executes by crontab it gets some strange value like
**...041704300440043504330438044104420440043804400430432043004304304304304304404370430432043004420435043043504390447043504400435043704320430044804430430...**

I don't know how to debug it because, when I run the script manually it works, but fails with strange value when executed by crontab.

The text in the site is russian, encoded with *Windows-1251*.
Maybe there is something wrong with that. 
I have set `# encoding: utf-8`, in the .rb file.

Comment: That is a bad assumption. We run Ruby scripts from crontab that handle all sorts of data without problems. It's all in how you set up your environment.

Comment: Deleted my wrong assumption about unicode and solution with -Ku flag.
Thank you.

Comment: This isn't a forum. Please don't put the solution into the question! Choose the right answer below by checking it, or answer it yourself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be an environment problem, which could include bad paths, etc. You can compare your ENV from the command-line to the environment when launched by crontab.

Try:

```
ruby -rpp -e 'pp ENV' > /tmp/crontab_env.out
```

from crontab, then:

```
ruby -rpp -e 'pp ENV' > /tmp/cmd_env.out
```

from the command-line, then:

```
vimdiff /tmp/*env.out
```

or use a regular editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RVM, note that it is typically only available to interactive shells. There's a whole section in the RVM manual dedicated to this topic: [RVM: Ruby Version Manager - Using Cron with RVM](https://rvm.io/integration/cron/)

It could be that this is simply a problem of the wrong Ruby version, including its Gems, being used. Try removing the hashbang line in your script, and calling it like this in your crontab:

```
1 0  * * * /usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby-1.9.3-p362 /path/to/script.rb
```

This should make sure the proper environment is loaded with the Ruby binary.

If the actual problem is that RVM isn't even available for non-interactive scripts, you could also go one step further and do what your shell does when it's loading RVM—scroll to the right, this is a big line:

```
1 0 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" && rvm use 1.9.3-p362 && ruby /path/to/script.rb
```

Comment: If that doesn't work, I'm not sure where the actual error is. You said your script "gets a value like…", but what does that mean? Is that the value it extracts from the website in `new_user_count.scan`?

Comment: Thanks, but RVM doesn't seem to be the reason why my script doesn't work.
When I launch it by hand from the console the regexp on the cyrillic string works. But in the mail from crontab, I have then following error 
/home/ec2-user/ruby/login.rb:43:in `scan': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)

Comment: That could be an environment problem, which could include bad paths, etc. Try comparing your ENV from the command-line and then from when launched by crontab.

Comment: Try `ruby -rpp -e 'pp ENV' > /tmp/crontab_env.out` from crontab, then `ruby -rpp -e 'pp ENV' > /tmp/cmd_env.out` from the command-line, then `vimdiff /tmp/*env.out` or use a regular editor.

Comment: I've compared the diff output, and of course LANG variable was missing. That's what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Problems with cron jobs are often caused by having the wrong environment.  The script probably depends on an environment variable that's set when you start an interactive shell (through `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc` or similar), but not when your program is started directly, by cron.

Get a list of environment variables and their current values by typing `env`.  Add a cron job that simply runs `env`.  Compare the outputs and chip away until you find the culprit.

I'd say `LANG` and friends are a good place to start.  Get a list of language and encoding-related environment variables by typing `locale`.

Comment: I have tried setting the locale in ~/.bashrc, but here it was not the case, because it wasn't working this way.